# list-style in ie7 not functioning

Tags: css

I have a simple setup like so..

```
ul { list-style: none; }

    #navigation ul li a {
    padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
    line-height: 32px;
    float: left;
    color: #dedede;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

And then a list.

```
<div id="navigation">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#">etc</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">etc</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">etc</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">etc</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">etc</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

The intention? The list items should render, side by side, in a straight line. Hunky dory in FireFox, IE8, Chrome, and Opera.

IE7 (and 6, too) displays them in a jagged stair-style, though. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm concerned about the second selector in your CSS -- the 'navigation ul li a' one.  You've commented-out the selector line, but aren't the subsequent lines essentially invalid CSS?  Will this make IE7 (but not the other browsers) throw out your CSS entirely?

Comment: I've not commented out the line; Stack Overflow is just displaying it like that for some reason.

Comment: @Drew: `#` is not a CSS comment. It's an ID selector. Feel free to report an issue at [Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/).

Comment: doh!  Of course... was just thrown by the way it appeared on the page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For IE you will need to add `display: inline;` for the li tag.

So:

```
* #navigation ul li { display: inline; }
```

Comment: Thank you. Though it still ignores the box-model that the other browsers follow; Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: This is why web designers hate IE, IE uses a box model that is a little different.  

I'm testing it in IE7 at the moment and it looks the same as it does in firefox 3.6 (with that code at least).  Is there something I'm misunderstanding, or do you have more css to go with that?

Comment: Yeah, there is CSS around it, but way too much for this simple question. I'll see if I can hunt it down. It does work fine in IE8 though.

Comment: Here is a page that talks about it.  The area named "a workaround is possible" may help you arrive at a solution.

http://stuffthathappens.com/blog/2007/09/12/ie-and-the-css-box-model-wronger-than-wrong/

Answer (score 0):

You want to have the `float` on the `li` elements, not on the `a` elements. Here's the updated CSS:

```
#navigation ul li {
    float: left;
}

#navigation ul li a {
    padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
    line-height: 32px;
    color: #dedede;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```